# can't start oracle service in windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm taking DB prog. class and we are required to use Oracle+ Oracle sql dev. I so far I got 3 DB in oracle each with a connection from Oracle sql dev.

In windows services I only have one service called OracleDBConsole"MY1stDB name" there's no similiar services for the other DBs I created.

When I try to start this service I receive error as the picture

[image]

I can connect through the connections in Oracle sql dev. to the other DB I created except the 1st one

Does anybody have an idea on this issue

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*I got 3 DB*". It is very rare that you have more than one "database" in Oracle (note that a "database" in Oracle is something completely different than a "database" e.g. in SQL Server. If you have one service running, your instance is running and everything should be fine. And please post the error message as a text in this question (if only because my Antivirus system is blocking the site where you are hosting your picture because it is known to be a malicious site)

Comment: 3DB means I have created 3 Databases...take note that I'm using it for learning purposes not in Enterprise environment...I have uploaded the error as pic. because it appears as a pop-up box not in log file as txt.I have  edited my question and upload it in imageshake"hope it works"

Comment: Why on earth did you create **3** instances? That is almost never needed.

Comment: but the first 2 DB each was as requested for each of my assignments and the third one I just made it to test if when a new connection to new DB disturb the previous connections and I found that connection 2&3 is fine except one

Comment: You should have create three schemas (=users) instead. I'm pretty sure that your assignment did **not** request you to create a new *database instance*.

Comment: It did!!anyway how to get over this issue dude?

Answer (score 3):

As one of affected people, I finally found solution:

If this appears, run `lsnrctl start` as an administrator to start the listener.

Most probably your listener.ova and tnsnames.ova are improperly set.

Answer (score 2):

OK you installed 3 instances on same machine. There are two possibilities.

They are all set up to use default ports so when one is started no other can start due to port conflict. In that case you need to reconfigure ports following [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15660/app_port.htm)

Second possibility is you already have different ports for your instances. In that case please check your connection definitions if they use proper ports. First will probably need default 1521 but others needs other ports. You may try 1522 as when during instalation 1521 was used it could took next free. But generally you should go to `NETWORK/ADMIN/listener.ora` edit file and check what port is used. Then properly define connection in client tool.

But as said in comments. Installing 3 instances make no sense unless you're trying to do some study with `DBlinks` simulations.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioned service relates to oracle enterprise manager service.you have this because it configured for your database. but to troubleshoot it please check its logs in %ORACLE_HOME%**HOSTNAME_DBNAME**\sysman\log*. check there logs and send to investigate.
regards,
Mohsen

Answer (score 1):

There is insufficient detail about the error to know what the problem is, however my guess is that subsequent instances are attempting to use the same resource as the already started instance, most likely the port.

Nevertheless, your problem can be solved by **not creating multiple instances** of Oracle, but rather **creating multiple databases** in the one Oracle instance.

It is a virtual certainty that your teacher did not intend you to start multiple instances of Oracle.